# ¿como puedo contar el numero de veces que una clase de mi elemento html cambia?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

El caso es el siguiente:

Tengo 3 elementos del tipo div que hace un `carousel` con `boostrap` y en esos divs hay una clase por default que se llama `item` y cuando el div esta seleccionado o visible a ese item se le agrega otra clase que se llama active, lo que quiero hacer es contar las veces que cada uno de mis elementos items llegaron a contener la clase active.

Codigo html:

```
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div runat="server" id="CarouselHtml" class="carousel-inner" style="height: 500px;">
Aquí se genera el código de los slides con la clase item
            </div>
            <a href="#carousel" ID="tagLeft" onclick="waitchange();" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a  href="#carousel" ID="tagR" class="right carousel-control" onclick="waitchange();";  data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

El código html que son los divs con las clases items se generan mediante C#

Answer (score 0):

Podes bindear el evento slid;

```
$('#carousel').bind('slid', function() {
    var indexSel_ = $('div.active').index() + 1;
```

slide

> slid.bs.carousel: Occurs when the carousel has finished sliding from one item to
>   another.
>   slide.bs.carousel Se produce cuando el carrusel está a punto de
>   deslizarse de un elemento a otro.

slide:

> slide.bs.carousel Occurs when the carousel is about to slide from one
>   item to another.
>   slide.bs.carousel Se produce cuando el carrusel está a punto de deslizarse de un elemento a otro.

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp